# iOS7 - How to change the the tintcolor of a UIButton for UIControlStateHighlighted

Tags: ios, ios7

Changing the tintcolor in iOS7 is awesome because it uses the image as a mask, so you don't need multiple images for multiple tint colours.

As far as I can tell, you can't change the colour for another other state (like UIControlStateHighlighted) - it defaults to a slightly paler version of the tint colour.

I'm looking for something like setTintColor:(UIColor *)color forControlState:(UIControlState)controlState.

Anyone know how to do this?